# What is the simplest circuit that would turn on in either one of two possible state with close to equal probability?

Tags: circuit-design

I'd like to make a circuit that would be in either of two possible states where each state has close to equal probabilities.

ie. If I turn on and off the circuit enough times, it should get close to 50% state A and 50% state B.

What would be the simplest circuit that would have this behaviour? Ideally using only transistors or simple IC

Comment: I suppose you don't want a MCU with built-in true random number generators to give the numbers to you? Because, building a true random number generator from scratch is extremely diffcult.

Comment: This is actually a much more difficult problem than you probably expect. Randomness is *hard*.

Comment: "Most likely state B" is contradictory

Comment: @Justme Correct Ideally just transistor and/or simple IC

Comment: I've edited the question a bit

Comment: @silkAdmin It is your second sentence that makes a quantum system like Stern-Gerlach a requirement.

Comment: A transistor or simple to use IC cannot provide you randomness with near 50% chance to power up in either state. Unless the simple to use chip is an MCU.

Comment: I like this application. My first thought was a 6T SRAM cell, however I suspect an individual/specific SRAM cell may end up being pretty deterministic or at least biased.

Comment: @Bryan I understood none of that but thanks for the lead. I will dig on it.

Comment: @Bryan SRAM cells nearly always start up the same way. It might not be consistent from cell to cell, but  you can be sure it'll be pretty consistent (probably better than 95%) for repeated trials with a single cell.

Comment: @Heart that’s what I suspected. I always received the knowledge that “sram initial contents are random” but it makes more sense the process of making sram generates cells with random biases.

Comment: How about a square wave into a latch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a circuit that is quite close to my requirements.

Using JK flip-flop IC, with both J & K are always on, and clock is connected to voltage with a small capacitor in series.

With this setup, when I turn on the power, either Q or "Q not" are activated in what seems to be close to equal probability.

Answer (score 2):

IF you already have experience with writing, debugging, and programming a microcontroller . . .

THEN nothing will beat an 8-pin, $1 uC programmed with a lookup table of random 1s and 0s.

There are many websites dedicated to lists of random bits, bytes, and words.  All pseudo-random lists repeat; the question is how long before they do.  Would a list of 10 random bits be enough for your application?  100?  1000?  It's all just typing.

If you really want a more physics-based solution, then try this.

A "standard" zener diode or reverse-biased transistor white noise source driving a clipper to produce a random 1 and 0 bit stream.  Couple this with a 1-second (or shorter) delay that captures the state of the bit stream after it has been running for a short time.

Noise Source >> Clipper >> Timer >> Latch

Just winging it, I think all of this can be done with 1 CD4011 quad NAND gate, a transistor for the noise source, and a few R's and C's.  One of the gates is used as a linear amplifier to bring the noise voltage up to a level that can toggle a gate input.

If this sounds like something within your skill set, I can whip up a concept schematic.

Comment: I do have experience programming but I am trying to learn electronics so I'd rather keep it physics based for this experiment. Thanks a lot for the leads. I will dig further on those

Comment: I does not sounds within my skill set at all but I'd appreciate the schematic, I'll probably learn from it

Comment: The pre-programmed lookup table feels a lot like https://xkcd.com/221/ to me.

Comment: That maybe an option. The point of this is to learn anyway. Would you be able to provide a link to a 8pin uC you mention? After a quick google I can't find anything relevant

Comment: I think the intent is "any $1 microcontroller", because no special hardware is implied.  A "lookup table of random 1s and 0s" is purely software.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the 50% randomness gives you:

1. Free-running Ramp or triangle generator 0-100% (transistor oscillator).
2. After Off make a sample of the ramp state (transistor sample&hold).
3. 0-50% gives you A, 50-100% is B (simple comparator at ramp/2).

**Edit:**
If you want a really simple solution for beginner go circuit below:

After switching SW1 ON the C5 begin to be charged via 10K, at some level the comparator (Q5,Q6) flips to On state and runs an astable multivibrator (Q1,Q2).
To multivibrator output is connected a SR latch (Q3,Q4) which changes state periodically according multivibrator.
Once you turn Off SW1, the C5 discharges and at some point flips the comparator (Q5,Q6) to off. The last state of multivibrator stays in SR latch.
So each Led connected on SR outputs should have 50% randomness.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbyF8Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Unfortuanalty I understand none of those options. I am googling it but if you could expend on them I'd really appreciate

Comment: I think "turn on and off the circuit" means turning on and off the power to the circuit, not a control signal.  If the latter (control signal), then this is a very simple problem - 3 gates.

Comment: @AnalogKid Correct. What I am trying to achieve is without a control signal

Comment: @silkAdmin Is it allowed the oscillator is already running when you switch power ON?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický no because this is running on a battery and power saving is a concern. Could an oscillator approach work if the oscillator was powered on at the same time as the rest of the circuit ?

Comment: @silkAdmin No, the condition to get randomness is that the oscillator has unpredictable state when switching power ON. Btw, the oscillator can be designed to have consumption less than 1mA at 4V battery.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický That could be an option then. Would you mind describing how to approach that ? FYI that circuit is running on a 3.7V battery.